# How to transfer ERC721 token to address from the smart contract?

Tags: solidity, tokens, erc-721, nft, transfer

I am working on a smart contract (`OpenZeppelin ERC721`), where trades can be created by only the owner of smart contract, and then regular users can buy them.

When owner creates a trade, a new `ERC721` token is minted, with smart contract itself being the owner of the new token.

The problem is, when I call `transferFrom` in the `buyTrade` function above, it reverts with the error of `"ERC721: transfer caller is not owner nor approved"`. I think, as the buyTrade function is public, `transferFrom` function is called by the caller of the function, and that address is not the owner or approved. Is there a way to run `transferFrom` function by the smart contract itself?

Note: I know about the `approve` method, but since I don't know who will buy the trade, I can't approve that specific address in the `createTrade`. Or am I missing something, is this design wrong?

Here is the related code, truncated unnecessary parts (events, checks etc.):

```
function createTrade(bytes32 tradeId, uint256 amount) public onlyOwner {
    // check if any trade exits with the same Id etc.

    uint256 newTokenId = _tokenIds.current();
    _tokenIds.increment();
    _safeMint(address(this), newTokenId);

    require(createInternalTrade(tradeId, newTokenId, amount));
}

function buyTrade(bytes32 tradeId) public payable {
    // check if tradeId exists, in sell list
    // check if minimum price is met etc.

    transferFrom(address(this), msg.sender, trade.tokenId);

    // emit events
}
```

I really appreciate any help.

Comment: try "this.transferFrom(...) -> this will transform the "msg.sender" from the caller to the address of the contract which is the owner of the token. you actually dont need transferFrom and can use transfer directly. However take care and use this solution at your own risk

Comment: Thanks @MajdTL. Are there any security concerns about using ```this```?

Comment: No, but I can’t see the rest of ur logic, code and what u exactly want to do. Using “this” make ur contract call his method like an “external” caller

Comment: If this works then tell me to post that as an answer